# What is the place in the office people grab coffee and snack?

Tags: word-request

It is not necessarily a room but can be small area in the office, has a coffee maker, fridge, microwave, sink and cabinets holding seasoning, paper towels and utensils. Sometimes there is a vender machine too.

is it a pantry?

Comment: **It's a pantry** synonyms - larder, buttery.

Comment: Related at EL&U: *[What is “a room a company provides for eating food” called?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279451)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [no single term](http://www.pinterest.com/ofwny/pantry-breakroom-lunch-room-cafe-canteen-dining-ar/); depending on the organization, the facility, and the primary use, that area may be the

- *[break room](http://images.businessweek.com/ss/07/10/1014_office_collaborative/index_01.htm)* (US) or *[restroom](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/restroom)* (UK) - a place, as you note, where one might go for a coffee break (and in olden days, perhaps a smoke break)
- *[lunchroom](http://www.nytimes.com/1981/05/31/realestate/company-lunchrooms-go-fancy.html)* - a break room with sufficient tables/counters and seating for people to eat lunch in, but can also refer to [any place](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/03/06/dining/the-lunchrooms-of-capitol-hill.html) people take lunch, which might be a *cafeteria* or *dining room* (see below)
- *[pantry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pantry)* - sometimes synonymous with the above, especially if on the smaller end of room sizes. But *pantry* has many different uses, and is more generally a storage area for dry goods attached to a kitchen or dining area (ranging in size from a particular cabinet to a walk-in closet).
- *[canteen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canteen)* or *[mess](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mess#mess__12)* - probably adopted from the military terms for a small facility with food or drink for sale, or a recreational area where food is served
- *lounge* or *[staff room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staff_room)* - a room reserved for employees to socialize, eat, or relax, especially if non-staff are present in the facility (e.g. retail store, school)

Some people may lazily call it a *kitchen*; however, as a *kitchen* is a room for preparing meals, having a "full kitchen" implies cooking equipment like an oven, range, or deep fryer, and not just a toaster or microwave oven. Conversely, if the area is used primarily for serving meals, it may be a *refectory* or *dining room*, or a *cafeteria* or *commissary* if the food is ordered a la carte from a counter.

Comment: +1 for "no single term". However, at my last place of work we did indeed call it "the kitchen area", or "the kitchen" for short. Probably because none of the other words really fitted, for the reasons you've given.

Comment: @starsplusplus Likewise with my last place of work and "The Kitchen". Where I currently work, we refer to it as "downstairs" (?!), since it's the only thing in the basement besides Billing.

Comment: We refer to it as the "watering hole"

Comment: Don't confuse "break room" and "restroom" in the US

Answer (score 5):

The word you're looking for is probably *[kitchenette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitchenette)*.

Comment: thanks but there is no stove so is it qualified as a kitchen-like function?

Comment: Definitions of it or money say "small kitchen", and I've certainly heard and used the term in reference to the type of area you're describing. The lack of a stove doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: You can use "Kitchen" to refer to any room where people frequently prepare or handle food.

Comment: True, I suppose the reason I think _kitchenette_ is appropriate is that _-ette_ has become a productive suffix for things diminished in size or utility.

Comment: @jimsug I've edited in a definition link to Wikipedia because this post appeared in the VLQ queue. Please remove or change the link if you feel it's not appropriate or what you meant.