# What is the name of a room in which hotel staff use to store their equipment and provide room service?

Tags: american-english, british-english, terminology

Is there any special word for the room that hotel's stuff regularly use to provide room service for guest rooms? is it something like staff room? or service room?

[image: a picture]

Comment: Yeah it is a room.
One of my friend is supposed to label the rooms of a hotel. Hotel's owner suggests "room services" for the mentioned room. However "room service" is actually  a hotel service enabling guests to choose menu items for delivery to their hotel room for consumption there, served by staff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [terms for a room where staff can take breaks](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24489), what the space is called may vary by person, by organization, and by facility.

In American English the room in your photograph would be commonly known as a *janitorial/janitor's closet* or room, or *custodial/custodian's closet* or room, storing equipment and supplies used by the cleaning staff. The job of cleaning may be handled by a *caretaker*, *cleaner*, and so forth, with a corresponding adjustment in terms; in a hotel, the department in charge of cleaning guest rooms is *housekeeping*.

A web search on these terms will return a few photos, but as they aren't usually a selling point of a facility, they are mainly referenced on sites trying to sell cleaning supplies or services and in things like [facility regulations](http://www.med.umich.edu/facilities/plan/dg/05/doc/5.5.1-11Jan.pdf). Also, the terms *janitor* and *closet* are not used consistently around the world.

The space might also be known as a *utility closet* or *supply closet*, signifying spaces used for storing equipment and supplies for facility use in contrast to a *[stockroom](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=stockroom)* which is where you would store extra merchandise for sale.

A smaller space just for storing equipment, in which a person could not or would not walk around inside, might be known as a *broom closet* or less commonly a *mop closet*.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing that I can think of would be [**a utility room**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_room):

> A utility room is a room within a house where equipment not used in day-to-day activities is kept. "Utility" refers to an item which is designed for usefulness or practical use, so in turn most of the items kept in this room have functional attributes.

I think generally, though, that would be called a broom closet (that's by far the most popular term). However, what's in the picture obviously does not look like a closet. It's a room.

Comment: "Storage room" or "supply room" might also work.

Comment: Supply room sounds better to me, because the room is actually used every day,